# Restricting Non-Admin Users From Stopping a Process in Task Manager C++

Tags: c++, windows

In C++ and using the WinAPI; I am trying to start a process with admin rights using CreateProcessWithLogonW(), from within another application that does not have admin rights, but the new process can be stopped from within task manager by the non-admin user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Chaman

Comment: Does the process that is started have a window? Is it being stopped by "End Process" or by "Kill Process"?

Comment: its window process and is stopped by EndProcess

Comment: That's your problem then - any process with access to the desktop can send a message to any window on it, so anything can just send a WM_CLOSE to your app's top-level window.

Comment: i think i answered your question wrongly...i mean its console process on windows O.S., and it has been stopped by taks manager 's button endprocess

Comment: At first, you should redefine WM_CLOSE so that it won't actually close your app. And then you'll have to take care of Task Manager. I remeber tutor explaining us the solution to this problem, but unfortunately I don't remember. I believe it involved hooks.

Answer (score -1):

As I can remember, Create admin process from non-admin process is very hard in windows.  The simplest option to start admin process is to build that process exe with admin privilege, and use ::ShellExecute.

In vista and win7, posting message to admin process from non-admin process is not allowed. you may need to create your own message queue to send msg to admin process in order to kill it. (boost message queue can be one option). Or you can use some other sync techniques to kill it.

Comment: He doesn't want to kill it, but prevent non-admin users from doing it.

Comment: <pre> but the new process can be stopped from within task manager by the non-admin user.</pre>Did he mean let non-admin user to kill it from task manager?

Comment: yes i want to prvent from nonadmin user to kill or stop this process.